# What is the most hostile environment to hide something?

Tags: earth

If I were to hide an artifact, where would could I hide it so that it is the hardest for a human to get there (or even be there).

For example, hiding something inside a volcano sounds like a pretty smart idea, because no one could possibly get there, or find it by accident. Or throw it on the bottom of the Ocean, because the chance that I'll be found would be pretty small. Or at Chernobyl; nobody wants to go into a broken nuclear reactor.

What are some examples of good hiding places (on earth) so that other people couldn't get there by accident?

Comment: `What are your thoughts, on where to hide stuff, so that people couldn't get there? Or make it for them as hard as possible.` - I'm sorry to have to say, but what you're asking for is our opinion and is not really an appropriate question to be asking on WB.SE; perhaps try refining your question to make it fit better

Comment: Also consider adding some limitations to your question. It seems that you want to hide your stuff somewhere on earth. We are on WB here so it's not that obvious.

Comment: All of Chernobyl's reactor #4 is just to be picked apart. Just now the New Safe Confinement... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_New_Safe_Confinement ...is being slid into place over the old "sarcophagus", with the intent that the sarcophagus and the broken reactor shall be picked apart and the contaminated parts taken to permanent storage.

Comment: Title is about one thing, body of the question is about another. Please make them consistent. Walking in and out is very far from "living in".

Comment: You do want to be able to retrieve the thing you are hiding, right?

Comment: What is the size and composition of this artifact?

Comment: The Idea would be to be able retrieve it, but can should be very hard.

Comment: The size doesn't really matter, it's more about the place. I thought of somethig between the size of a backpack and the thing Indiana Jones was carrying in Raiders of the lost Arc. But feel free to come up with something completely else (size).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In Plain Sight

The problem with the places that you mention is that if it is hard for other people to go there, it would be hard for you to go there too. It is difficult to store things inside a volcano, since such things would likely melt.

I argue that the best place to hide something is in plain sight. There are lots of megacities in the world crawling with people, and many of them have large areas of slums which are largely ignored by the world around them. If you have your secret evil McGuffin stored in a shack in Kinshasa, or a favela in Rio de Janiero, or Dharavi, Mumbai, who would find it? If people did find it, would they know what it was, or even be able to report it to anyone?

It isn't like the residents of those places are connected to the world information economy in a way that such knowledge would widely disseminate. And it isn't like fearless journalists, scientists or explorers are just dying to go wandering through a crime ridden slum of millions. I think the thing you are hiding will be quite invisible.

Comment: If your secret item is in a shack in some slum, what guarantee do you have that it's there when you return?

Comment: @Innovine I would assume that if you are an evil mastermind, you can come up with some evil henchmen to guard your evil valuables.

Comment: That'd only attract attention

Answer (score 3):

TSINGY DE BEMARAHA NATIONAL PARK, MADAGASCAR is very inaccessible just because of the limestone needles.
there are several unexplored cave complexes on earth.
deep sea trenches are actually bad places if you want your thing back, lots of landslides to bury it. how durable is your thing?